# NFTs minted but dont appear in OpenSea

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft, opensea

I created a NFT contract and the 20 NFTs initially minted when the contract was created appeared in my OpenSea Account. When I used the mint function to create another 100 they show up in PolygonScan but do not show up in OpenSea. Any advice on why and how to get them to show on OpenSea?

Note the 20 currently listed.
https://opensea.io/collection/embassybuddhas

Note the PolygonScan states 120 have been created and assigned to my Address.
https://polygonscan.com/token/0xdc195e1b0f2efd089b8990c911e6d7093acec7df#balances

[image: Note the 100 that was minted using the mint function.]

Comment: Hi @michael-downey, thanks for sharing this question! I've been having the same issue on Opensea testnet. I've minted a test collection and everything looks okay on that. But as you mention here, it's not appearing on the Opensea testnet (the records are there, but the files are not visible) (https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/kanda). Seems like your collection is now available and looks great, can you give me a tip on how you resolved that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not mint more than your maxMintAmount

If you do it will error out and create these ghost tokens

Comment: Hi @Michael Downey , where did you find maxMintAmount at ?